# How to move the camera on x- and z-axis so that viewpoint targets (0,0,0)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

*I meanwhile found a solution, but I'd really like a code review. Perhaps there is an easier solution. I updated the script at the end of my question.*

I have a camera in my scene with a specific position and rotation. I want to move the camera on the x- and z-axis so that it targets (0,0,0).

I have the position vector `posVector` of the camera object and the displacement vector `dirVector`, which is the viewing direction. Now at some point, `posVector` + `dirVector` will intersection the ground plane. This currently is (x,0,z) but I like to move the camera on the x- and z-axis so that this is (0,0,0). So I really need to know x and z.

I tried multiple things, but I still have trouble wrapping my head around vectors and intersections.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DebugHelper : MonoBehaviour {
    public Camera mainCamera;

    // This DebugHelper script runs in EditMode and will help me visualize vectors and also move the camera to where I want it to be.

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 posVector = mainCamera.transform.position;
        Vector3 dirVector = mainCamera.transform.rotation * Vector3.forward;

        // Find scalar for dirVector that displaces posVector.y to 0
        // posVector + dirVector * scalar = (x,0,z)
        float scalar = Mathf.Abs(posVector.y / dirVector.y);

        // Get the position vector of the current camera target at y=0.
        Vector3 y0TargetVector = posVector + dirVector * scalar;

        // Subtract the y0TargetVector from the posVector to move it back to zero. This works because y0TargetVector.y is 0 and therefore the height is the same.
        mainCamera.transform.position -= y0TargetVector ;

        Debug.DrawRay(posVector, dirVector * scalar, new Color(0, 1, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm lost by what you mean with "it targets(0,0,0)".

Comment: if you want a "code review" then post it on code  review. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Galandil x=0,y=0,z=0 world space

Comment: I know perfectly well what is the `Vector3.zero`. It's not clear if you want to set the camera position at those coordinates, or just make it to LOOK AT those coordinates from everywhere the camera is positioned.

Comment: @Galandil no offense, I misunderstood the question. I want to move the camera's x- and z-position so that it looks at (0,0,0) without changing y-position or rotation.

Comment: None taken. So basically your camera can translate freely on the X,Z plane (but it always stays at Y=0), and you want it to point always at (0,0,0) - i.e.: its forward vector is always looking for the origin of the axes. Right?

Comment: No, the camera is on a random position e.g. (300,700,-500) with a random downward rotation e.g. (50,-30,0). Now it should be moved on the x- and z- axis so that it looks at y=0. Does this clarify it?

Comment: I think so: from a random position and rotation, you want to translate the camera from (x,y,z) to (x,0,z) and you want to rotate it such that the camera in that (x,0,z) coordinate looks toward the (0,0,0) point. Right? Does this have to happen after a specific event (for example a button press)?